# Akka.NET ConsistentHashingPool: create routee per hash

Tags: akka.net

Is it possible to force [ConsistentHashingPool](http://api.getakka.net/docs/stable/html/22F13748.htm) to create routee per hash? I want one routee actor to process only messages of the same hash. And if new hash comes in, then new routee is created.

I tried looking into `Resizer` class, but I was not able to figure out the way to achieve the thing I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the [ConsistentHashRouter (CHR)](http://getakka.net/docs/working-with-actors/Routers#consistenthashing) a bit. It already does what you've stated—consistently routes messages whose keys fall in a given hash range to the same routee.

Routees are added to / removed from the CHR routee table as new nodes/virtual nodes join the cluster. Then, the hash range will be rebalanced to account for the new nodes in the cluster and the CHR will route messages to the node that is now responsible for the part of the hash range the key falls into. This may be the same node that was responsible for it before, or it may shift from one node to another. Essentially you're sharding the hash range across the cluster.

UPDATE: as of writing this (October 2015) this management process must be done manually. There is a module coming called Akka.Cluster.Sharding that will do the rebalancing of shards for you across nodes. It is currently available on the JVM.

Comment: I understand that it routes the messages to the same routees. But as you say, the routee is responsible for the range, not for the specific hash.  
And I want to have routee per hash.  
On the diagram from your documentation lets say that B Z X A are hashes, not the messages. And I want hash B to be sent to another routee created 'on the fly'.
[Diagram](http://getakka.net/docs/images/ConsistentHashRouter.png)

For me it already looks like I am mixing two different problems.

Comment: @derwasp I think, that you're asking for solving problem with consistent hashing while the thing, you're really looking for is cluster sharding - it's a module that is in development phase (at the moment of writing this comment), which will be able to automatically create and rebalance actors over the cluster and send them messages by specific id. You can see it already in the akka on the JVM.

Comment: @Horusiath thanks! After looking through the documentation for the JVM akka it looks like this is the thing I need. Since I am not in a rush, will wait for it to be ready ;) I can not accept you comment as an answer though. So it's either you post it as an answer or I will just accept Andrew's.

Comment: Yeah, @Horusiath is right. Cluster sharding--once available--will do what I described above for you. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Seems a bit like an overkill to me for such a simple use case. You want all message with an specific Id to be handled by the same actor. If it does not exist than create it. Simple like that. Do you really have to use clustering and additional modules for that?

Answer (score 1):

(From a newbie perspective...)
I agree with Oliver, this is too simple a use-case to *require* things called clustering and sharding.
Consider an actor holding some state for a user or a session or something - obviously each actor must receive only the messages for that entity-instance-id.

From having read a few docs I'm pretty sure it's trivial to code yourself:  You just write a parent actor which checks for the existence of a child for a given id, creates it if it doesn't exist, then routes the message to it.

I also expected there to be something like a create-unique-actors setting on the ConsistentHashingRouter to do this automatically for you.  (Maybe it's not generally useful since you need to consider when and how to terminate the actors to prevent them from living for ever?)

Comment: Several answers to other questions already detail how to do this.  E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39914840/52840 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/40201969/52840