# What is the correct way to resolve an actor

Tags: c#, akka, akka.net

I have 1000 orders and I want to create an actor for each unique orderid. What would be the best way to safely create these actors while guaranteeing that I only have one per unique orderid?

I have tried to first use ActorSelection, then if I can't find an actor with that id, I use ActorOf to create a new one, but when starting batches of these I will get a lot of ActorNotFoundException and when I then try to use ActorOf it fails with InvalidActorNameException.

Example:

```
try
{
    actorRef = await actorSelection.ResolveOne(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000));
}
catch (ActorNotFoundException)
{
    actorRef = Actor.EwmsActorSystem.ActorOf<T>(actorId);
}
```

Comment: I would solve it in a different way. Send all messages to a single actor who mantains a map of orderId -> actorRef, for each order check if an actor is already created (lookup in map) if so send the message to this actorRef. Otherwise create a new actor, save it in the map and send the message to the created actorRef. You can also forward the message instead of sending it.

Comment: Map is the same as dictionary in .net, right? I was considering storing the IActorRefs, but wasn't sure whether that was good practice or not.

Comment: As far as my .net knowledge goes, I think so, Map is a Dictionary.

Comment: I've seen saving ActorRefs in maps often, when each actor should take care of a specific part of the domain problem, so I don't think it's considered a bad practice

Comment: An [identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39905090/akka-net-is-there-a-a-way-to-get-or-create-actor) was asked on SO already not so long ago.

Comment: You don't need to keep a dictionary; the `Context` object has all the necessary info about child actors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [Entity Per Child Pattern](https://petabridge.com/blog/top-akkadotnet-design-patterns/), i.e. have an actor that spawns child actors per entity ID. You can view an [example](https://github.com/petabridge/akkadotnet-code-samples/blob/master/Cluster.WebCrawler%2Fsrc%2FWebCrawler.Service%2FActors%2FApiMaster.cs) in the World Crawler sample.

In a nutshell, it should look something like this:

```
var child = Context.Child(entityId.ToString());

if (child == ActorRefs.Nobody)
    child = Context.ActorOf(...); // spawn child actor here

child.Tell(message);
```

It is also good practice to set a ReceiveTimeout on the child actors, to kill them off when they have been idle for a period of time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will update my code and test this out.

Comment: @Gigi:  Thought I'd make the name with which the actor _must_ be created explicit rather than implicit. Cheers.